# WIA - how to check scanner if adf(feeder) capable?

Tags: c#, wia

im using **WIA scanner library** in my code.
i succeed to do the scans with the static scan type:

WiaDev.Properties["3088"].set_Value(1);

now i need to detect if the scanner capable of Duplex/Feeder so the users be able to select the scan type according to their needs.
to do that i need a scan combobox with 1.Flatbed 2.Feeder 3.Feeder(DUPLEX) options and i remove static input type from my code.

im looking for a way to check attached scanner  have a feeder tray and is it ADF capable or not in c#?

Comment: Please provide more detail. 

Comment: hi mate.im new at wia .i'm working on an app for scanning the document  from a  flatbed/feeder/duplex.i have a combo box which will populate upon which capabalities attached scanner will have.for example if installed scanner just have a flatbed combobox will have just a flatbed comboboxitem and if it also  has a feeder tray and can do ADF scanning capabalities  so the combobox will populate with 1.flatbed 2.feeder so the user be able to select the source for scanning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-wiaitempropscannerdevice)

> WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_CAPABILITIES
> ScannerDeviceDocumentHandlingCapabilities Contains the capabilities of
> the scanner. The minidriver creates and maintains this property. An
> application reads this property to determine whether the scanner has a
> flatbed, document feeder, or duplexer installed. This property is also
> used to further define the installed features.

and

> The following table describes the constants that are valid with
> Windows XP or later.
>
> DETECT_FEED   The scanner can detect a document in the feeder.
>
> DETECT_FLAT   The scanner can detect a document on the flatbed platen.
>
> DETECT_SCAN   The scanner can detect a document in the feeder only by
> scanning.
>
> DUP   The scanner has a duplexer.
>
> FEED  The scanner has an automatic document handler installed.
>
> FLAT  The scanner has a flatbed platen.

Comment: yes.i read them all and i know the properties WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_CAPABILITIES has a attribute DUP/FEED/FLAT .what i dont know is how to read and use this attributes.